# Skimage.draw.ellipse generates two undesired lines

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a boolean image, where the zeros are the background, and I want to plot the ellipse that encloses the major and minor axis of an object retrieved from `skimage.measure.regionprops`. The module `skimage.draw.ellipse_perimeter` generates the expected ellipse but also two undesired lines.

Code (the input image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYLE0.png)):

```
import skimage
import skimage.draw
from skimage.measure import label
from skimage.measure import regionprops
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load example image
TP_mask = plt.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYLE0.png')

# connect region with same integer value
region = label(TP_mask)

# obtain RegionProperties
props = regionprops(region)
props = props[0]

# define centroid
y0,x0 = props.centroid

# draw ellipse perimeter
rr,cc = skimage.draw.ellipse_perimeter(int(x0),int(y0),int(props.minor_axis_length*0.5),int(props.major_axis_length*0.5), orientation = props.orientation)

# plot
plt.plot(rr,cc, color = 'yellow')
plt.imshow(TP_mask, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

However, if I create a simplified example as follows, I obtain the expected ellipse. Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((1000,1000))
img[200:800,200:400] = 1

region = label(img)

props = regionprops(region)

props = props[0]

y0,x0 = props.centroid

rr,cc = skimage.draw.ellipse_perimeter(int(x0),int(y0),int(props.minor_axis_length*0.5),int(props.major_axis_length*0.5), orientation = props.orientation)

plt.plot(rr,cc, color = 'yellow')
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share your input image with us so we can run the code and help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Thanks! That helped me find the answer for you! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the coordinates returned by the `draw` module are designed to index into an array, as shown [in this example](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_shapes.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-shapes-py), rather than plot:

```py
rr, cc = ellipse_perimeter(120, 400, 60, 20, orientation=math.pi / 4.)
img[rr, cc, :] = (1, 0, 1)
```

To use `plt.plot` and do a line plot, the coordinates need to be sorted as they go around the circle/ellipse. They are *not* properly sorted by default because the ellipse is actually drawn in four separate quadrants, which you can find by [looking at the relevant part of the source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/1188c33c3defefdc0f672870b5bcc36beaec967f/skimage/draw/_draw.pyx#L517-L529). (A clue: the lines hit exactly where the ellipse is vertical or horizontal.)

Since you have a convex surface, computing the angle between each point and the centre of the ellipse is enough to sort the points. Try the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
_ = ax.imshow(TP_mask, cmap='gray')

angle = np.arctan2(rr - np.mean(rr), cc - np.mean(cc))
sorted_by_angle = np.argsort(angle)
rrs = rr[sorted_by_angle]
ccs = cc[sorted_by_angle]

_ = ax.plot(rrs, ccs, color='red')
```

Which gives:

[image]